# Creating new categories from a text string in R

Tags: r, categories, stringr

I have a column with the Following rows:

```
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access
```

I want to create a new column based on the values found: i.e.

```
if Telephone line rental is found, then in the new column, I want to code as V
if Fixed broadband, then code as B
if Mobile phone = M
if Paid for TV service / TV and/or sport code as T
```

So if we take the first rows example:

```
Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access
```

The category will be: `V, B, M`
 The NET: XXX|NET: XXXX parts of the string needs to be ignored.

the full portfolio can be any combination of those 4 but they must be in the following order `V, B, M, T`

I have been googling and reading through `library(stringr)`

Tried splitting up the string with `sep = "\\|"` but it is not working.

Any other ideas?

Regards,

**DPUT:**

```
c("Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: No internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: No internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: No internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access", 
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access", 
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
)
```

Comment: @d.b I have added the column dput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grepl` like this:

```
df <- read.table(text='"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Telephone line rental|Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: Internet access"
"Fixed broadband|Mobile phone|Paid for TV service|NET: No home phone calls|NET: No home phone calls or line rental|NET: Internet access"',
header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

tv <- c("Paid for TV service","TV","sport code")

df$new_col <- paste(ifelse(grepl("Telephone line rental",df$V1),"V",""),
ifelse(grepl("Fixed broadband",df$V1),"B",""),
ifelse(grepl("Mobile phone",df$V1),"M",""),
ifelse(grepl(paste(tv,collapse = "|"), df$V1),"T","")
)
```

Comment: works like a charm but TV categories are not working :/

Comment: @Shery I wasn't sure about the rule for TV: is this three possibilities: Paid for TV service / TV and/or sport code ?

Comment: @Shery I fixed the TV part. `grepl` works a bit differently with multiple input strings.

Comment: @P Lapointe this is beautifully fixed the issue... but it doesn't fix the order of the new column for example if the `telephone line rental` for example I want to add another process who would change the order from `B M V T` to  `V B M T` so it doesn't matter what order the new column is...the order should always be like `V B M T`

Comment: @Shery The order will always be VBMT no matter where "telephone line rental" is found on the line.